# If I close an sqlite database, is it safe to copy the db file immediately?

Tags: sqlite

I want to immediately copy an Sqlite database file after closing the db, so is this safe or is it asynchronous in that the close function does not wait until everything is complete? I.e. is there risk of corruption if you copy a db file using OS file operations, imiediately after the db is closed?

My guess would be that there is no issue and the close of the db ensures now it is safe to make a copy of the file on the drive... But I want to make sure, as a corrupt copy of a database would be a huge headache, and likely intermittent bug not always occuring.

The close call to the db will not be in a separate thread in my program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQLite library runs in your process, and does not use threads (except for sorting).

So it is guaranteed that after closing, any operations done through this connection are complete.

However, this does not prevent other processes from accessing the database file. Better use the [online backup API](http://www.sqlite.org/backup.html) to make a copy.

Comment: There will be only one application using this database at a time, so it should work... But the backup api may be the safest bet in the future if it is decided the database will expand to multiple apps. Thanks for the answer.